# How to make QPushButton not to be triggered by Enter keyboard key

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton

The code below creates a single dialog window with 5 buttons. Each button is connected to `onClick` function. If I hit 'Enter' keyboard key one of the buttons is triggered and it `onClick` function is executed.

How to change the buttons properties so the buttons call for `onClick` function only when they are clicked and do not respond to `Enter` keyboard key?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui 

def onClick():
    print 'button clicked'

dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
dialog.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
for i in range(5):
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button %03d'%i)
    btn.clicked.connect(onClick)
    dialog.layout().addWidget(btn)
dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `default` and `autoDefault` property of the `QPushButtons` to False. E.g.

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button %03d'%i, default=False, autoDefault=False)
```

What you are observing is the the QDialog's special handling of the enter key to trigger the default ['dialog action'](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#default-button) (it is a common gotcha when using QDialog).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that it is the interaction between Qdialog and QPushButton that bring the 'Enter' key to trigger the action associated with the QPushButton.